# mprotect in linux

Tags: linux, copy-on-write, mprotect

If I `mprotect` a segment with PROT_NONE and if a `SIGSEGV` occurs due to a write which gets handled by `sigaction` with `sa_sigaction`, We will be able to find the address where the fault occurs using `siginfo_t`'s `si_addr`. But is there a way to find the data and the length of the data that was tried to be written ?

I am trying to do this because I trying a copy-on-write mechanism for my project.

Comment: The kernel is doing exactly what you told it to do here, which is all `mprotect()` is designed to do. You could use it if you wanted to implement CoW (as hinted in answers), however _expecting_ frequent SEGVs is probably not a good design decision. Your best bet is to manage your own pool, which unfortunately means writing your own allocator. You can still use `malloc()` within it, but children need to use the one you provide (and corresponding `mprotect()`).

Comment: This is not a HW. I am trying to do this as a part of learning process and implement a continuation optimization ( or it might de-optimize even. I dont know.). Once I do it , I wanted to benchmark it again getcontext and setcontext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't find the data the process tried to write, nor does it make sense to ask about its size. If you could get the data it would mean the kernel had already copied it somewhere.

You get a `SIGSEGV` on an entire page. That is, regardless of the data the process is writing, you will get exactly one fault per page - the first time you try to write a byte. So all you need to do is:

- Keep track of page state
- Increase permissions as needed

Comment: Isn't _expecting_ lots of SEGVs as business as usual a bit of a .. well .. bad idea?

Comment: @TimPost It is. But I suspect this is a homework where the student needs to `mmap` some memory with no permissions, write to it and add permissions as it goes. I once had to do this (I see no practical purpose in it but it's pretty cool).

Comment: I suspect you're probably correct. I think I'm going to work through this later just for the fun of it.

Comment: I once had to do something similar for a very practical purpose. I had some code that needed to run both on SMP and UP machines. On UP machines, the overhead of the `lock` prefix was painful. So we used `ud2` instead of lock. The `ud2` opcode is guaranteed to cause a fault. We caught the fault and "patched" the instruction at run time to `lock` on SMP and `nop` on UP. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @cnicutar 1. What exactly do you mean "Keep track of the page" ? You mean make a copy of the entire page ? If so where do I get that information ? 2. When there are more than 1 update , do I make as many copies as the number of the updates ?

Comment: @bsoundra By "keep track" I mean keep a data structure of your own of of `page_address:page_state` mappings. You don't need to copy anything.

Comment: @cnicutar when you say `page_state`, I can think of only making a copy. Because there needs to be a old state and new state. What am I missing ?

Comment: @bsoundra You only need the state. Which can be: `NOPERM`, `READ`, `WRITE`.

Comment: @cnicutar Ok . But how do I use this mapping, if at some point I prefer to restore the page with older information. i.e. I prefer to revert back to the older information present before the write performed on the protected page.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel doesn't know, so it can't tell you. But you can try to find out if you want. You have the code address that faulted on the stack, so you can disassemble the code there to try to figure it out. There is no other way to know (think about it if it's not obvious to you why). The instruction faulted because it touched a protected page, that's all that's known unless you analyze the assembly code.

If you can't tell what object you're dealing with by knowing only the page that faulted, I'd strongly suggest you reconsider changing your design so that you do. (`posix_memalign`, perhaps?)

**Update**: Don't forget that you need to have a hook that's called on every context switch. You may need to copy pages around on each hook. For example:

1. Context A is accessing page Q with CoW semantics. Context A gets read-only access to the page.
2. Context B is accessing page Q with CoW semantics. Context B gets read-only access to the page.
3. Context A goes to modify the page, we make a copy for context B. Context A now has write access to the page and modifies it.
4. We switch from context A to context B. At this point, you **must** switch in the copy of the page you made for context B.

Note that the other way around this is to have contexts make specific calls to map and lock pages. That won't work if you allow a context to hold a mapping across a context switch -- at least, not without a lot of extra work.

Comment: I think I have not communicated the issue properly. The approach is CoW but I want to do something different. When the write is performed I want to make a copy of the existing page & store it off in data structure and continue making the changes to the current page. When I wish to make a roll make I copy the old page in place of the current existing page.

Answer (score 1):

When you use mprotect() you know the starting address and length of the memory segment you're protecting. You need to store that information somewhere so you can use it later.

Once you've protected your memory segment, if you access it in a way that violates the protection you'll get a SIGSEGV signal. In the signal handler you'll get a pointer to siginfo_t. This gives you the information you need. si_addr gives you the address of the instruction that caused the illegal access, and si_ptr gives you the address that was accessed illegally. You then compare si_ptr to the memory segments you've protected until you find the one it belongs to, and that's the one you need to copy for your "copy on write"... once you've done that you then need to call something like setcontext() or siglongjmp() to continue running from a known location.

I hope this helps.